# ListPopUpWindow in ScrollView in Android

Tags: android

I have created `ListPopupWindow` in `Activity` containing `ScrollView`. When I show it by setting a view that is at the bottom of the screen as the anchor point and the space at from the anchor point to the screen end is less than the height of the `ListPopUpWindow` it shows a thick border around it.

Please suggest how to remove it.

Added Code here

```
listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(this);
listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.list_item, list));
listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(vwFirstOptionUnderline);
listPopupWindow.setWidth(vwFirstOptionUnderline.getWidth());
listPopupWindow.setHeight(android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
listPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.boarder_around));
listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listPopupWindow.show();
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: please provide your code with a screenshot of the problem

Comment: @ZygoteInit, Added code and screen shot.

Comment: I will look at this soon ... just post a comment tomorrow if you get impatient

Comment: I got the solution of my own. I used background for the ListPopupWindow, I removed the background solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found this bug on android 
just once dismiss it and show again like this :

```
listPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
listPopupWindow.show();
listPopupWindow.dismiss();
listPopupWindow.show();
```